# Wordpress Login Fine on Internal cant on External

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which is hosted on machine `192.168.1.9`, with an external IP of `212.159.x.x`. I can login locally just fine, and it transforms to `212.159.x.x`.

I can browse the site from the external IP fine, as well. But if I attempt to login via the external address, its not allowing me. I have changed the `wp_options` table to the site_url and home to `212.159.x.x`. Browsing works, just not accessing the admin interface. Is there a specific way to whitelist the external address?

Comment: Some additional information about your networking setup would be helpful here. How is the hosting machine set up? Is it behind a router that is handing it an external IP, or behind NAT?

Comment: @NateBarbettini sorry yes therouter is hadling the extnerip address the hosting machine is windows 10 which i have forward the port on the router to port 80 as say can login fine on dashboard local ip just not extnernal even though i change wp_options vars to the external ip address